# Python returns invalid path with pip command

Tags: python

i'm trying to install a package with python.
i copied the ssl certifcate in a folder.

Then id did this:
pip config set global.cert c:\Users\me\SSL\mycerticate.crt
it returns: writing to c:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini

Then when i try this:
pip --proxy http://127.0.0.1:9000/localproxy.pac install robotframework

it returns:
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: C:\Users\me\SSL\smycertificate.crt

Why the path is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a typo in your path.

c:\Users\me\SSL\mycerticate.crt

C:\Users\me\SSL\smycertificate.crt

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape `\`:
`pip config set global.cert c:\\Users\\me\\SSL\\mycerticate.crt`